# How to store a text file to an Array <double> using the Double.parseDouble(string s) method

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have text file called numbers2.txt that I need to store into an `ArrayList<Double>` using the `Double.parseDouble(string s)` method. I have no idea on how to do this.

Here is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Operator {
    public void createArrayList() {
        String[] math = {"add ", "Subtract ", "multiply ", "divide ", "remainder ", "Greaterthan ",
                "lessthan ", "max ", "min ", "power"};
        Scanner file = new Scanner("data\numbers2.txt");
    }
}
```

The text file includes:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BufferedReader` to load the file.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("<Filename>"));
```

After loading the file, you can store the value from text file to a `String` variable line by line.

```
String line = br.readLine();
```